# How to publish a docker image using buildpack's `pack build --publish`?

Tags: docker, buildpack

I am using [buildpack](https://buildpacks.io/) to build a docker container, and I want to publish it to a remote container registry.

I am using this command:

```
pack build myapp --builder heroku/buildpacks:20 --publish
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to : ensure registry read access to myapp
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 1
```

How can I specify the remote registry URL and credentials? I tried running `docker login` before running my command but received the same error. The [documentation](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/cli/pack_build/) only says the following:

```
--publish                     Publish to registry
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows the same principles as `docker tag` and `docker push`.

1. You need to `docker login` to your target registry first. `pack` will also use this to authenticate with your target registry.
2. You need to use the format `<registry-host>:<port>/<project>/<image>:<tag>` for the value of your image name. This is the same as with `docker push` and this is how both utilities know where to send the image.

   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#push-a-new-image-to-a-registry

For example:

```
pack build docker.io/user/myapp:v1.0 --builder heroku/buildpacks:20 --publish
```